# Rails: Error in action "Timeout::Error in CarsController#show"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geoip

When I load my action `CarsController#show` in browser, I get this error message:

```
Timeout::Error in CarsController#show

execution expired
```

And the error pointing out on this line:

```
country = GeoIp.geolocation(ip, :precision => :country)
```

The whole action:

```
def show
    @car = Item.find_by_car_key(params[:car_key])

    ip = request.remote_ip
    geo_key = 'my geo key'
    GeoIp.api_key = geo_key
    country = GeoIp.geolocation(ip, :precision => :country)
    puts country.inspect

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @item }
    end
  end
```

How can I avoid this error message and use it always when this action will be loaded?

Thank you

Comment: What does `GeoIp.geolocation` do? Perhaps it's running a long process that's causing your request to time out?

Comment: `GeoIp.geolocation(ip, :precision => :country)` just find out the current location of the user who browse the website. "Perhaps it's running a long process that's causing your request to time out?" -> No, because I see the error like 1 second after entering the URL. The gem is called **geo_ip**.

Comment: Ruby debugger can help solve this type of problem. Put a debug statement in and check line by line to see what's failing and why. https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger

Comment: If you made a question, please take time to give us feedback, you have a couple of asks, please review it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the GeoIP gem found [here](https://github.com/jeroenj/geo_ip)

The error is related with the time out, maybe geoip gem is taking to much time to fetch the ip info, so after your Api Key set GeoIp timeout

According to the gem readme,

> It is possible to set a timeout for all requests. By default it is *one second*, but you can easily set a different value. Just like you would set the api_key you can set the timeout:

Try

```
 GeoIp.timeout = 5 # In order to set it to five seconds
```

#### Update

I will recommend you another gem, because geoip is nor uptodate, take a look at Geocoder
https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder, it can take the ip address from the request automatically like

```
request.location.country
request.location.city
```

Comment: maybe provide some doc of what the default timeout is.. if it's the same time that the OP is experiencing, this could be very valuable

Comment: It depends on which gem are you using, can you tell me? because in https://github.com/jeroenj/geo_ip#timeout the default is 1 second

Comment: I would recommend setting up the client in a initializer, instead of each request.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) gem in combination with maxmind or freegeoip
works well in my production app (freegeoip sometimes detects the wrong country, but its free)